# Remove residue from bacon grease

Tags: bacon

I use bacon grease for cooking during the week. I have an issue though. I always get residue from the meat when I poor it out of the pan.

How can I filter this out? I can use a spoon for some of it, but it's just not effective to get more than 2/3 of it.

Comment: Growing up we had a small aluminum container with a built in filter under the lid, worked a treat. I'll bet they still sell such things.

Comment: Many years ago, I would pour a (slightly cooled) fresh batch of baking grease into a clean glass jar (unstrained), let it sit on the counter for a bit to settle, then store it in the fridge for the week.  The solids would fall to the bottom, and it was obvious from the clear glass what level the 'clean' grease was.  Of course, it doesn't work if you keep adding to the jar, as then you have a mix of hot grease going over the cold grease.  And I wouldn't do this if you're not going to be using the grease within a week or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fat can be filtered through a coffee filter. It's slow, but it works. Make sure the fat stays well above the temperature at which it congeals.

Alternatively, you can "wash" the fat by mixing it well with some boiling water and then letting it cool and separate. The impurities (at least, the particulate matter) should go into the water and be more easily removable.

Comment: The chunks from bacon cooking are usually large enough that a paper towel works pretty well, too.  (although these days, they tear into such small sheets, I don't know if you'd have problems with the perforations ... I have a fancy canning funnel w/ two filters, so I haven't used paper towels in years)